# Dynamic Named Subpatterns for RegEx?

Tags: php, preg-match

I know I can use named subpatterns in preg_match to name the row in my array: `(?P<sval1>[\w-]+)`. The problem I have with this is that "sval1" is predefined. Is it possible to make this named subpattern as part of the regex lookup itself?

For instance, if the text field is as follows:

```
step=5
min=0
max=100
```

I would like to use a preg_match to create an array with essentially:

```
{
    [step] => 5
    [min] => 0
    [max] => 100
}
```

The user would be able to add as many fields as they want to the text entry; so it needs to dynamically generate the array entries based on their input. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Interesting tought, but no. It would require something akin to `(?P<$1>..)` which PCRE does not allow. But just use `array_combine` instead with `preg_match_all` here; that's usually a convenient method for associative pair matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = 'step=5
min=0
max=100';

$output = array();
$array = explode("\n",$str);
foreach($array as $a){
    $output[substr($a,0,strpos($a,"="))] = substr($a,strpos($a,"=")+1);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
```

or:

```
$str = 'step=5
min=0
max=100';

$output = array();
preg_match_all("/(.*)=(.*)/",$str,$matches);
if(isset($matches[1]) && isset($matches[2])){
    foreach($matches[1] as $k=>$m){
        $output[$m] = $matches[2][$k];
    }
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
```

or based on the comments:

```
$str = 'step=5
min=0
max=100';

$output = array();
preg_match_all("/(.*)=(.*)/",$str,$matches);
if(isset($matches[1],$matches[2])){
    $output = array_combine($matches[1],$matches[2]);
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: oh! i don't know how i missed that. nice spot

Comment: Could use `$output = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);` instead of the loop, otherwise +1 the second half sample seems the best approach.

Comment: instead of doing `if ( isset($_foo) && isset($_bar) )` you can simply do : `if (isset($_foo, $_bar ...)`

Comment: a combination of the comments lead to a third, and more efficient answer